# When I am looking at a method that is called on an interface, how do I go to the code the implements the method?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

We have lot of code like:

```
IPerson
{
    Eat();
}

Persion : IPerson
{
}

IPerson p;
p.Eat();
```

As most of our interfaces only have 1 or 2 classes that implement them, there should be a way for me to right click on the “p.Eat()” and be taken to the code the in person class.  When there is more than one implementer, I wish to be shown a list to choose from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new feature in Visual Studio 2010, called **View Call Hierarchy** (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+T).

Right-click on a symbol in code (method name or properties are good) and select View Call Hierarchy, and you will get a new window with various options.  On interface members, you will see an 'Implements [member]' option, dropping this down will show you all instances where the interface member has been implemented.

Similar options appear for virtual / abstract members, showing you where they are overridden or implemented.

As an extra bonus, this window also shows 'Calls To [member]' and 'Calls From [member]'.

Answer (score 1):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is an extremely valuable refactoring tool which provides the behaviour you describe.

I currently right click on the method name in the interface file and select the option 'Go To Implementation'.

I'm assuming this is a Resharper feature and not just Visual Studio 2010 purely because you aren't aware of it. Try right-clicking and seeing if you have the option. If not - I highly recommend getting a refactoring tool with this kind of functionality.

Comment: Even quicker than that, with R# `Alt`+`End` (in the VS keybinding scheme) while on the interface member will popup a list of implementing methods, or go straight there if there's only one

Answer (score 0):

Edit | Find and Replace | Find Symbol will find definitions and references.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on p.Eat() and choose "Find all references". In the Find Symbol Results windows, you may find all of the implementations of that interface method. Double-clicking each item will show up the reference in code editor.

Comment: That also find all the **calls**, some methods are called 100s of times.